# Count Distinct Over Partition By, Based on Another Column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, distinct, partition

I have a table with relevant columns A-C below, trying to achieve D.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | JOHN | 0 |
| B | 456 | MATT | 3 |
| B | 456 | MATT | 3 |
| B | 456 | MATT | 3 |
| B | 456 | MATT | 3 |
| B | 789 | MATT | 3 |
| B | 234 | MATT | 3 |
| B | 967 | ELISA | 1 |

The logic is - if Column A = 'B', Column D should return the number of distinct values for Column B, partitioned by Column C.

I think I'm really close to the solution - currently I have this logic:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN A = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY C)
```

However, this returns 6 for 'Matt' above, counting all rows, not just distinct. I would want to see 3, for the unique IDs '456', '789', and '234'. Throwing a COUNT(DISTINCT) into the CASE WHEN statement seems to blow the whole thing up. I've been wrestling with this for a while and so far unable to find a solution. Is there a way to do this in one line that I'm missing or do I need to start adding subqueries/CTEs?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

NVM I figured it out.

`CASE WHEN (A = 'B') THEN COUNT(DISTINCT B) OVER (PARTITION BY C) ELSE 0 END`

appears to give the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if "distinct" keyword can be used with over clause in SQL server. Not sure about other databases though. I have come up with the solution which can do the trick. Please see below.

```
select a.* , 
       case when a.ColumnA = 'B' then b.counT_CoulumnB
            else 0 end as ColumnD 
from col as a inner join
(
    select 
        ColumnC ,
        ColumnA , 
        count(distinct ColumnB) as counT_CoulumnB 
    from col 
    group by ColumnC , ColumnA
) as b on a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA and a.ColumnC = b.ColumnC
order by a.ColumnA , case when a.ColumnA = 'B' then b.counT_CoulumnB
                          else 0 end desc;
```